# What is most appropriate test?

Tags: estimation, likert, agreement-statistics

I have conducted a survey using 5-Point Likert scale (Strong Agree;  Agree etc.) in which a panel of experts indicated their Agreement with suggested statements.

There are three sub-Groups within the expert panel

I am interested in evaluating the significance of Agreement for each of the different groups.

My challenge is that my sample size is small (n=14).

Can I assume normality?

Is Chi-sq test of contingency tables appropriate?

Comment: Please make your question title more descriptive.

Comment: 'The significance of Agreement' do you mean inter-rater reliability (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability) and things like Intraclass Correlation Coefficients (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation)?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to compare the 3 different groups and test if their responses to the survey are different? You may want to take a look at Kruskal-Wallis test.